# OpenCV and VS 2015 Exception thrown: null pointer from imread

Tags: c++, opencv, null, visual-studio-2015, null-pointer

I am getting some null pointer errors when executing the release version of some image processing code I wrote this week.  It has been a long time since I have worked with C/C++, so I am pretty confused.  I am working with OpenCV 3.1 in VS 2015 Community, and my code is compiling and running without issue in the Debug environment.  However, when I run it after compiling in the Release environment, I get null ptr errors right at the beginning.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
```

I am pretty sure it is throwing exception from the very opening lines.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // reading in both tif files
    Mat bg = imread(argv[1], 1);            
    Mat rad_film = imread(argv[2], 1);
```

The error I get is

> Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
>
> this was nullptr.

it seems for some reason it is reading a null image/matrix, but I have no idea why, especially since it has no problem in the Debug environment.

The debugging also points to this method in the Mat class as the source of the problem

```
inline void Mat::release()
{
    if( u && CV_XADD(&u->refcount, -1) == 1 )
        deallocate();
    u = NULL;
    datastart = dataend = datalimit = data = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dims; i++)
        size.p[i] = 0;
}
```

Specifically it is giving &u and "this" as issues.  I am not sure how to interpret this.

The two images I am processing are both .tif files.  I am very new to both OpenCV and Visual Studio, and while I have run into some confusion this week, this is the first issue where I am really lost.  Any help is very much appreciated!

Edit:  libraries I am linking for both release and debug are:

as far as libraries go, I am using the following for both release and debug:

```
'opencv_calib3d310d.lib'
'opencv_core310d.lib'
'opencv_features2d310d.lib'
'opencv_flann310d.lib'
'opencv_highgui310d.lib'
'opencv_imgcodecs310d.lib'
'opencv_imgproc310d.lib'
opencv_ml310d.lib
opencv_objdetect310d.lib
opencv_photo310d.lib
opencv_shape310d.lib
opencv_stitching310d.lib
opencv_superres310d.lib
opencv_video310d.lib
opencv_videoio310d.lib
opencv_videostab310d.lib`
```

Comment: What does the debugger say? What's the value of `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`? Perhaps it wouldn't be a bad idea to validate them before blindly passing them as a parameter to further code... Furthermore, it would be nice to upload the image files that give you trouble (don't convert them to a different format), so others can try to reproduce this issue. Oh, and is this 64bit code? Where did the OpenCV binaries you're using come from? Which libraries are you linking with in Debug and Release respectively?

Comment: the value of argv[1] = 'film_bg.tif' and argv[2] = 'film.tif', respectively, and are printed through cout without issue.  These are indeed the correct file names.

Unfortunately, I cannot upload the images for proprietary reasons, but I think really any .tif will work.  The files are unsigned 8 bit in 3 channels.

I'm building it as a Win32 app, and all the OpenCV files came from the OpenCV website.

I've edited in my included libraries above.

Comment: In release you should link to libraries **without** the trailing "d"

Comment: Greak, thank you @Miki.  I think this resolved that problem - now I just have to figure out where the rest of the release libraries are for OpenCV...